# Decoding authorization token before or after passing request to an aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-eks

I have a full stack website whose frontend (React) is hosted on S3 bucket and accessed via aws cloudfront. My backend microservices are spring applications which will eventually be hosted as a kubernetes cluster on eks. I am using aws cognito for authentication purposes and I have a header named authorization which contains a token for each user in every request to the backend.

I want that when I make a call to my backend services in my frontend code, the authorizer in the header of the request gets changed to the decoded user before reaching my cluster. I was thinking of keeping the eks cluster behind an api gateway. Now I don't understand how and where exactly I can decode the token. I looked into things like lambda authorizer, lambda@edge and cloudfront functions but I am unable to reason how these are helpful in my case.

My first thought was that I can hit some lambda function which can return a decoded user and then the api gateway can hit the endpoint of the cluster but a single method in api gateway cannot hit 2 services in the backend. Is there any way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Is there any issue in decoding the user info from the JWT token? Because, that is more secure, and will save you from unnecessary hacks.

Comment: Do you mean in the backend itself? Like the spring application ?

Comment: Yes, why you don't want to decode there?

Comment: I have 5 spring microservices in the backend and api gateway will be used to route to the correct one. I thought instead of writing a decoding logic in all 5 of them, I can probably decode it before at some common point before sending it ahead.

Comment: I agree with @AnkushJain that you really should do it in each place.  Have a common library to parse it and get what you need.  It's some trivial String processing - don't prematurely optimize, especially around a security area.

Comment: Ok, it looks like that's the best way to go about this then.